# How to install recent clang++ with Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, development

I've tried

```
brew install llvm
```

but after that I cannot find any `clang++*` executable under `/usr/local`.

Thus my question: How to get clang++ via Homebrew?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of 2018, the [Homebrew Versions repository ('tap') is out of service](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions).

The stock Homebrew llvm package still doesn't include clang/clang++, by default. Thus, it isn't part of the prebuilt ('bottled') package.

One can build it via:

```
brew install --with-toolchain llvm
```

And then use it via e.g.:

```
$ PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH" \
    LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib' \
    cmake ...
```

But this `--with-toolchain` induced build takes a very long time and is thus unsuitable in a continuous integration (CI) environment.

However, the clang that comes with recent XCode  (which is available in CI environments like Travis-CI, Version 9 is the default, 10 available, too) isn't that outdated anymore as it used to be (Apple uses an fantasy version scheme for clang that doesn't match upstream clang version numbers but cmake detects e.g. for AppleClang 9.1.0.9020039 the version 4.0.1). Thus, it is sufficient to build C++11/C++14 software with common dependencies like Boost (e.g. version 1.67).

### 2016 State of the Art

The `llvm` package in Homebrew doesn't include `clang++`, by default. When installing it, you have to add `--with-clang` to the command line (e.g. `brew install --with-clang llvm`). The extra `--with-clang` yields a full package compile because there is only one prebuild ('bottled') `llvm` package available (without `clang++`). In addition to that: the `llvm` package is relatively old - currently it has llvm 3.6 - where 3.7 was released 6 months ago.

Thus, to get a bottled `clang++` 3.7 you have to install the llvm package from [Homebrew Versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions):

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
$ brew install llvm37
```

It is then available under:

```
/usr/local/bin/clang++-3.7
```

The formula also notes:

```
To link to libc++, something like the following is required:
  CXX="clang++-3.7 -stdlib=libc++"
  CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -nostdinc++ -I/usr/local/opt/llvm37/lib/llvm-3.7/include/c++/v1"
  LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/usr/local/opt/llvm37/lib/llvm-3.7/lib"
```

Comment: Note that if you're doing this for Emscripten, you have to use the clang version they provide.

Comment: The latest Homebrew `llvm` (3.9.1) in the `homebrew-core` tap now includes `clang`, `clang++`, etc. under `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin`

Comment: Complement to @ssdecontrol's comment: there's a `--with-toolchain` argument now that some users might need. More info here, https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/2/20/installing-clangllvm-on-osx

Comment: Shadowtalker is right, and since then, `--with-clang` argument has been removed.

Comment: @shadowtalker, do I have to execute `brew install --with-toolchain llvm` as @hangtwenty is suggesting or is `brew install llvm` sufficient? With the `--with-toolchain` option the package is compiled - which is very time-consuming - in comparison to just installing a prebuilt (bottled/binary) package.

Comment: as of December 2018 I'm getting `Warning: llvm: this formula has no --with-toolchain option so it will be ignored!`, and it can't install due to compilation errors in Mavericks, so I resorted to download precompiled binary from https://clang.llvm.org/ and it works.

Comment: `Error: invalid option: --with-toolchain`

Comment: Can someone who knows the current best way to do this clean up all the old/incorrect info from this answer?

Answer (score 44):

Now it's enough to run:

```
brew install llvm
```

The bottle now includes `clang` by default.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: @Tetsujin I agree with you, but this is essentially a full answer. It fully describes what is needed and why

Comment: Just for the confused, as it's keg only, the binary for clang will be in e.g. /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/12.0.1/bin/clang or whichever version you have.

Answer (score 5):

The --with-clang and --with-toolchain options don't work anymore. This worked for me:

```
brew install llvm
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
open .
```

and then run the installer.

I compiled with

```
CC=/usr/local/cellar/llvm/7.0.1/bin/clang CXX=/usr/local/cellar/llvm/7.0.1/bin/clang++ make
```

Comment: Unfortunately homebrew binary clang is broken. It doesn't include `/usr/local/include` folder as base include dir, so all software build fails. Clang provided by xcode doesn't have `fsanitize=leak` and `ccc-analyzer`. So both clangs on mac os is broken. You have to build it with all features enabled from source. But compilation will kill your CI like travis. So you have to host and maintain separate CI only for apple. Apple is good only for simple development, anything else requires pain.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install it with `--with-clang` option:

```
$ brew install --with-clang llvm
==> Installing dependencies for llvm: cmake
==> Installing llvm dependency: cmake
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/cmake-3.4.3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring cmake-3.4.3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Emacs Lisp files have been installed to:
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/cmake
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.3: 1,980 files, 27.4M
==> Installing llvm
==> Downloading http://llvm.org/releases/3.6.2/llvm-3.6.2.src.tar.xz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading http://llvm.org/releases/3.6.2/cfe-3.6.2.src.tar.xz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> cmake -G Unix Makefiles /private/tmp/llvm20160211-42310-16fdrbw/llvm-3.6.2.src -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEAS
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
LLVM executables are installed in /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin.
Extra tools are installed in /usr/local/opt/llvm/share/llvm.

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include


If you need Python to find bindings for this keg-only formula, run:
  echo /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/llvm.pth
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.6.2: 1,350 files, 338.2M, built in 21 minutes 18 seconds
```

Then, you will find `clang++` on **/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++**.

Comment: Hm, is it possible to still get a pre-built binary package (i.e. a 'bottle')? I mean when specifying `--with-clang`? I am asking because I intend to call that in a continuous integration environment ...

Comment: If exists, I down know about it, but I don't think that exists.

Comment: Actually, there is a bottled version available via Homebrew Versions. See also my answer.