# How to install and maintain multiple clang versions?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, macos

On my MacBook Pro I have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) as well as the [CUDA toolkit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/). OSX and Homebrew prefer the 'latest' version of clang (currently version 9.0.0). Clang is used for several Homebrew packages that I need. Without a recent version of clang, those packages won't compile (and brew won't update). But for nvcc, I am forced to use the older clang version 7.3.1. So I think I need two concurrent versions of clang.

I know that I can install a different version of clang by downloading and installing the version I need from the Apple Developers site, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250949/revert-apple-clang-version-for-nvcc), but there must be an easier way to work with two concurrent versions of clang (using some script to switch from one version to another).

I also found that, aside from using Apple's own commandline tools, I could use the LLVM package from brew, with the `--with-clang` option, [as explained here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227026/how-to-install-recent-clang-with-homebrew).

So my question is: how to use and maintain two versions of clang?

*PS: Just to show that I made the consideration: I know this question belongs somewhere in the grey area between Stack overflow and Ask Different. Please let me know by commenting if you think I am wrong to put it here; I'll move it to the other side if that seems to be the consensus.*